# Exim: how to rewrite a header to remove a string like +1234+?

Tags: rewrite, exim, regex, headers

Hi sorry for a bit of a newbie exim question.

For historic reasons we have email going through a smart host addressed to something like:    johnsmith+12345+@destinaton.com   (where 12345 can be any number)

We need to understand how to get Exim to rewrite and remove the +923423+ before it attempts to send to the remaining corrected address.

Our somewhat feeble attempts have failed :(

Be really grateful for any pointers as in how to do it and where in the conf file we should be doing it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would have been helpful to show what you already have tried.

Comment: Agreed, apologies. My attempts were so far off base I didn't feel they'd have added anything useful but I do see your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `exim.conf` file, there should be this line:

```
begin rewrite
```

Below that line you can place rewriting rules. You probably need a rule like this:

```
\N^(.*)\+[0-9]+\+@(.*)$\N $1@$2 tT
```

The `\N` pair indicate to exim that the enclosed string shouldn't be subjected to `$` and `\` handling. Then the first part is captured up to the numeric part with a plus before and after it, then the part after the `@` is captured. The replacement is simply the first and second captured string with `@` between. The `tT` flags mean to replace the To address in the header (`t`) and in the envelope (`T`).

It may be necessary to add a `S` flag to `tT` as this is on a smarthost and rewriting probably needs to be done at SMTP time.

Comment: This worked superbly straight off, many thanks for taking the time to help!